# I need to call 2sxc web api without anti forgery token

Tags: 2sxc

Im making an app for some form, and im colleting some not sensitive information.

I need to make an automatic report from a server, calling directly to report to download information, but im not being allowed to make the call because is being enabled automatically with antiforgerytoken, so if I make a get request from the server to a controller/action, im receiving an error, but if I make the call throw $2sxc(XXX).webApi, is working.

How i can make the 2sxc api call without antiforgery token

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple - just make sure you have `[AllowAnonymous]` on your class.

You can find working examples in the Mobius Forms app.

See also: https://docs.2sxc.org/web-api/specs/webapi-security.html
and https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/web-api/custom-web-api-security.html

Comment: I assume this helped, best mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks ijungleboy sorry I checked your solution immediately and worked. I just found another thing. I captured API call in browser but to make API calls is needed to change auto to controller name. I think this was a problem too.